# Share drawables between applications

Tags: android, android-resources

I have implemented plugin system in my applications. Plugins exist as the standalone applications.

What is the best way to access drawables from plugins in main application ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have few options:

- [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) - not definitely need to be based over `SQLite` database.
- manifest attribute `android:sharedUserId`

  From docs:

  > The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other
  >   applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own
  >   unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value
  >   for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID —
  >   provided that they are also signed by the same certificate.
  >   Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if
  >   desired, run in the same process.

  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid
- [PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the resources associated with an application.

  Usage:

  > ```
  > PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  > try {
  >     Resources resources = pm.getResourcesForApplication("com.example.app");
  >     int id = resources.getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "drawable", "com.example.app");
  >     Drawable d = resources.getDrawable(id)
  > } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  >     e.printStackTrace();
  > }
  > ```

Comment: Thank you. What about if plugin has defined hdpi/mdpi/ldpi drawables ? If I will call `getDrawable`, will it provide me the valid one ?

Comment: Yes, it gives you the valid one. You are getting the same `Resource` object as you would get by calling `getResources()` to retrieve `Resources` instance for your application's package. As you don't have access to `R.java` constants definition of your plugin apk, you have to get the resource by the name. You can also directly look at `R.java` of your plugin and use the constant `public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f02001f;` as an id, but that's a bit tricky.

Comment: I have registered `BroadcastReceiver` to gain informations about installed plugins, so I can also pass resource id of plugins' drawables. Ok, I understand everything. Thank you very much biegleux !

Comment: in case you are interested in getting a high res drawable, try this code:`resources.getDrawableForDensity(id, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)`
getDrawable will only return a drawable matching the DisplayMetrics of the device, lower or from the regular drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

I think ContentProvider is your best choice. They were specifically designed to "share data between multiple applications".
Here is a reference from developer.android:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html
And here is a detailed guide:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: I would not to store images in database. Plugins will be provided by 3rd party developers and it will be problem to implement whole SQLite to store just images. I was thinking about passing resource id and access image with it.