# How to attach .db file with another .apk android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-assets

i am making dictionary and i have so much data to load. I want that i create a project which first load the dictionary words in database and the after i use this .db file in my 2nd project which is dictionary project.

But i don't know how to get the .db file and copy it and paste it  into my assets folder.

Comment: Do you want do this in runtime?

Comment: no after data copied and .db file creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yopu cant simply copy any files from one private storage, to another. I suppose you can archive this using different ways, for example:

1) Copy your `.db` file to SD card by first app, and copy it back to private storage by the second app.

2) You can use [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to share private data between 2 different applications without moving it on SD card.

You can'not get direct access to assest or any other data folder of different application. Good luck!

Comment: by default the database is store in data/data/packagename/dbname. but how can i get this or copy this db ?? i want to see this file

Comment: Oh, you need rooted device to copy it, or you can run it on emulator ,for example, and use `FileExplorer` tab. On emulator you can access `data` folder of your app.

Comment: ok open the file explorer but now the data folder is not opening

Comment: It must open only on emulator only on rooted device. Do you use emulator?

Comment: yes i am using eclipse and when i attach my device i can see list of folders and files explorer but the 3rd folder which is data folder is not opening

Comment: on YOUR device it would not work. RUN you download app on Android Emulator. If you haven't any emulators - create it. Download you DB on emulator, and then copy it from Emulator. If you don't have ROOT acces to your device, this wouldn't work.

Comment: thankyou so much your's suggestion help me alot... once agian thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get resources from other package with PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication() method. Also you can share user id between your apps and sign them with share sertificate. In this case you can even share code base. +@Evos' suggestions.

I think share user id is your choise.

[You can find examples and more info in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626359/share-drawables-between-applications) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716607/accessing-assets-of-other-android-app-on-jelly-bean).

Comment: i only want to copy the previously cre4ated .db file and paste this in my another project because i have to give only one projects. in your given solution i have to give two projects

Comment: Easiest way is to share user id between your apks. Then you can access other project resources as your own. You do not need to code any (ContentProviders or coping db to some share location on sd card).

Comment: but when i upload my .apk the at this i have upload the oter one also on store to access ids

Answer (score 1):

Open Your previous project them open DDMS tab ,then go on path
data--->data---->your project---->databases--->.db file
now select that file and click on top right corner of screen here is a buuton to pull file from device to PC so click on that now a file dialog will appear select location to save file , now ok....this action will save your .db file on your selected location
now you can copy this file and put this file in your new projects assets folder and then use it.

Comment: Now to open the .db file you need a browser for sqlite which can be downloaded from net easily eg. sqliteManager for Mozzila firefox,sqlite browser etc.

Comment: thankyou so much your's suggestion help me alot... once agian thanks.. :)